# Navigation Drawer refresh/reload

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I managed to get my Nav-Drawer and Fragments work nicely. The problem I'm facing is, that I want the user to add new list-items to the Nav-Drawer and I'm doing this with a Dialog :

```
public void createAlert() {
    //ALERT
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Neue Liste erstellen");
    //alert.setMessage("Message");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            // Do something with value!

            dbHelper.createNewListItem(value, null);

        }
    });
}
```

My Nav-Drawer looks like this:

```
    // Erstellt den neuen MenuAdapter aus der Klasse MenuListAdapter
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, drawerTitles,  drawerSubtitles, drawerIcons);

    View footer = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_header, null);
    mDrawerList.addFooterView(footer);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
```

How can I refresh the listview (nav-drawer) after the Dialog is closed. I don't find any working solution. `notifyDataSetChanged` is not defined and none of these are working:

```
mDrawerList.refreshDrawableState();
mDrawerList.invalidate();
```

Anyone knows a solution ?

**Update:**

**this is my reload Method:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
    String listname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listname"));
    String listsubtitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subtitle"));
    allListNames[i] = listname;
    allListSubtitle[i] = listsubtitle;
    cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    drawerTitles = allListNames;
    drawerSubtitles = allListSubtitle;

    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, drawerTitles, drawerSubtitles,   drawerIcons);  
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
    mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Try `mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, i.e. `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter of the list view inside of the `DrawerLayout` ...

Comment: not working either, i think it the list/adapter doesnt recognize that i manipulated the data. .clear() etc is no option. So i just recreate the Fragment. Takes a lot of ressources but working for now.

Comment: Slightly strange - `notifyDataSetChanged()` worked quite well for me - have a custom adapter derived from an `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: notifyDataSetCahnged should work. In "this is my reloaded method" you call that method after you set the adapter it does not make sense. This method should be called when you make any change in the original source and you need to communicate to the adapter that should refresh the data, The the adapter review the arguments passed to him. I would suggest you to make sure you are changing in fact the data to be reloaded

Answer (score 3):

Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method and set adapter inside it. After that call `invalidateViews()` on your list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the item from ur navigatioView objct.

```
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_item_2).setTitle("Hello");
```